What exactly is the meaning of pressure at a single point in a fluid?
The pressure $p$ exerted by a force $\boldsymbol{F}$ acting at a point on a surface with area $A$ is defined as the ratio of $\boldsymbol{F}$'s component along the surface normal at that point and its area $A$.
$$p = \frac{||\boldsymbol{F}_\perp||}{A}$$
What do we mean then, when we say that the pressure at a given point in a fluid is $p$? Is it a measure of the force which an infinitesimally small surface would experience due to the fluid if it were placed at that point? How do we know that this force would be the same regardless of the surface's shape and orientation?

Are you familiar with the difference between average velocity and instantaneous velocity?

Yes, how is this connected?

For average velocity, you use an interval. You divide the total displacement by the total time. For instantaneous velocity, you take the limit of displacement over time as the time approaches $0$. For average pressure, you take an area. You divide the total force by the total area. For pressure at a point, you take the limit as the area approaches $0$.

This in no way answers my questions, though.

The pressure is defined in terms of an invariant of the stress tensor. Specifically, as negative one-third the trace of this tensor, it's the portion that doesn't change upon reorientation.
Elasticity theory predicts that pressure (or hydrostatic/dilatational stress, or equitriaxial stress) tends to change only the size of a body, whereas the remaining portion—the deviatoric stress—tends to change the shape of the body. The deviatoric stress is also the only portion that can be transformed to produce a shear stress. Since fluids can't sustain a shear stress, and since we don't observe initially still fluids at equilibrium to spontaneously rearrange, the pressure is experimentally consistent with its definition of being orientation independent. All other stress configurations would drive fluid flow until they are eliminated.
One can also confirm experimentally (e.g., by exposing a piston with different end shapes with equal area to equal pressures at the ends, and checking to see whether acceleration occurs from unbalanced forces) that the pressure is shape independent, which is consistent with the lack of a shape parameter in the definition.
